Why does re._compile exist?
Here is re.compile:
>>> import re, inspect
>>> print(inspect.getsource(re.compile))
def compile(pattern, flags=0):
    "Compile a regular expression pattern, returning a Pattern object."
    return _compile(pattern, flags)

It just calls re._compile with the same arguments.
What's the point of that? Seems like it just makes a useless extra stack frame, which is relatively expensive in Python. There should be a slight performance improvement, and simpler tracebacks, to just move the body of _compile directly into compile.
What's the reason for this technique using an extra function call re.compile -> re._compile?

Ref, introduced: https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/b1aa19515ffdb84c6633ee0344196fd8bd50ade0?diff=split&w=0

compile at least provides a default value for flags that _compile does not.

@chepner I see that, but if you "moved the body of _compile directly into compile" as the question says, the behavior should remain identical as far as I can see. Another way to phrase it would be to add the default value in _compile and then rename it to compile.

The link posted by Caramiriel suggests that compile used to have a more complicated implementation, and that _compile (with no default flags) was introduced to replace it. Given how rarely re.compile is needed, I'd bet it's just not a high-priority change to make.

They do mention an implementation hook. Perhaps related to that? Easier to replace the implementation to something different, such as a non-cached version or for instrumentation purposes.

@Caramiriel An answer demonstrating that this has been used, or even some mailing list evidence that it was intended to be used, would be an acceptable answer.
